# What fallacy accepts P and P → Q but rejects Q (denies modus ponens)?

Tags: logic, fallacies

I am finding that I can get people to agree with my premises, agree that my logic is valid, but then they deny my conclusion. For example, I state the sufficient conditions, P, for an optimal system, Q. They accept P implies Q. I prove P is true under my proposed system. Then they deny Q (they deny the system is optimal).

In short, what is the name of this fallacy: P and P → Q, but not Q?

Comment: And why are my dollar signs not making LaTeX?

Comment: Here's a meta article going into why it doesn't work here as it does on the math SE site: https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/43/29944

Comment: I will have to check further, but I would say it is not a fallacy since the argument is valid. That someone doesn't accept a valid argument might suggest they are irrational or unwilling to accept the conclusion. Oddly this might not be a bad thing. It forces both sides to come up with even better arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Frank. I'm not saying my argument is invalid. I know it's valid. I'm trying to find the fallacy of people not accepting modus ponens. I wouldn't say people not accepting an airtight argument and having to rely on emotional reasoning to get one's point across is "not a bad thing"; I think it is bad that people don't think logically. (But that's the way the world is, so regardless of whether I like it or not, I'll have to make those emotional arguments in addition to a logical one.)

Comment: It means that the people you are discussing with do **not** really agree that **P** is sufficient.

Comment: But they said they did think P is sufficient, and they didn't retract it.

Comment: You make the mistake of thinking the material conditional statement  equal to natural language. They are clearly distinct. For example I can use the form IF.. . THEN in many different contexts in normal English: If the Mets  win their next game, I will be a monkey's uncle. So would you accept my claim? You are using math terms. The parts of a conditional claim is called the antecedent and the consequent.  What you call the conclusion is properly called the consequent. Conclusion in philosophy means something else. All conditionals are not sufficient or necessary. That is your false assumption.

Comment: @Logikal Nope, you don't even know what my argument was. I was not sloppily using language in my proof, so your point about the distinction between natural language and logical reasoning doesn't apply and I have no clue why you assume it would apply. Unless you're claiming that logical reasoning using natural language is impossible, which is also incorrect. 

Thanks for the tip on using "conclusion" properly; I didn't know that. I suppose my proof was stating P → Q, and then showing S → P. So, would it be correct to say my conclusion was S → Q (system S results in the optimal outcome, Q)?

Comment: Your assumption that every phrase humans use in ordinary English can be phrased mathematically is dead wrong and so far from Aristotle up til now is impossible which is why only somethings can be translated.  Your argument form is not representative of ordinary language. You think all conditionals are necessary or sufficient which is not TRUE in reality. Your original form was modus ponens.  Your conclusion has to come from the premises.

Comment: @Logikal When did I assume every phrase could be phrased mathematically? I only said the phrases I used were phrased mathematically, which they were, and you have no reason to say otherwise because you don't know what my argument was. My argument literally says "There are three conditions that together are sufficient, but not necessary, to maximize..." And the person agreed with that statement. Your "monkey's uncle" example proves nothing.

Comment: You are not understanding what I wrote.  You still think that EVERY conditional has to be sufficient or necessary. My example shows every conditional is NOT. Conditional statements can mean different things depending on the context which you are not understanding. This is the reason why the person does not accept your consequent Q. The person accepts the antecedent and your question states why did the person not accept Q. There is no fallacy committed as you assume. Your phrase was CLEARLY not taken as a mathematical statement but a statement in natural language. Why the question if know this?

Comment: I understand your monkey's uncle example. But you think it proves it's impossible to make a logical argument with natural language, which it doesn't. Counterexample: Being a blue-eyed student is sufficient to be a student. That is a logical statement in natural language, regardless of what you think. And as far as you know, that example may be exactly what my argument was. You're claiming I'm "CLEARLY" wrong when you don't even know what I've said, which is ridiculous. Comments are not for extended discussion, so get in the last word if you wish.

Comment: You still don't understand clear English.  I specifically states all conditional claim do NOT express mathematical claims. You come back & state SOME are which does not address MY Claim and you attribute your OBVIOUS claim as if I was against it. I KNOW some conditionals express sufficient or necessary claims. You are the arrogant one who thinks All conditionals express a sufficient or necessary claim. Reality then slaps you when a human being accepted your antecedent and rejected your consequent! After that you posted this question. Before I responded what did reality show You?

Comment: Clearly it is possible for someone to accept the first part and reject the second. You make a a fallacy of hasty generalization & accuse me that I don't know what you are talking about. Your hasty generalization is that every time you see a conditional you think it must be a case of necessary or sufficient. I provide an example that is neither sufficient or necessary and it goes way over your head. In never said you can't make a sufficient or necessary which you WRONGLY attribute to me.  You have to stop making stuff up in your head & then blaming others for your thoughts. I never said those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a purely logical point of view, that inference makes so little sense that there really is no name for it.

However, if you run into a case like this in the real world, i.e. If you see some human agreeing to P, and to If P then Q, but not to Q, there could be several things going on.

For one, we could be dealing with a case of willful Ignorance, or willful denial, which isn't not so much a fallacy in the sense of a logical thinking mistake, but rather a result of other cognitive factors not making one accept what should be accepted. Possible reasons are wishful thinking or just being cognitively stuck on a certain idea or belief.

Another possibility is that the people don't *really* believe P, or that they believe that P is probably true, or true in most cases, but that in this particular case P does not hold, preventing the inference to Q. Same for If P then Q: maybe they *generally* believe that If P then Q, but that there are certain exceptions that apply to this particular case. And let's also note that their refusal to acccept Q is not necessarily the same as rejecting Q.

In short, the purely formal logical characterisation of their reasoning might just be too simplistic to capture the nuances that are going on. Indeed, the world is a messy place, so to think that we can make our way around with simple Modus Ponens's is a pipe dream.

Answer (score 2):

Named formal fallacies, like affirming the consequent, usually refer to inferences that can at least superficially be considered valid because they are often used as plausible inferences even when they are invalid (if smoke then fire, etc.). Denying modus ponens is not a mistake of this sort, so it has no name. And sometimes it is not a mistake at all, it is done to make a point that the meaning of terms, implication in this case, depends on the rules we adopt for manipulating them, like modus ponens. Someone may reject modus ponens because they decline to use classical implication, and prefer some alternative logic. Modus ponens fails in [Lukasiewicz's 3-valued logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2705757/152568), for example, but this is rare.

Denial of modus ponens was featured prominently in Lewis Carroll's dialogue [What the Tortoise Said to Achilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_the_Tortoise_Said_to_Achilles). The argument discussed is:

**A:** Things that are equal to the same are equal to each other

**B:** The two sides of this triangle are things that are equal to the same

**Z:** The two sides of this triangle are equal to each other.

The Tortoise points out to Achilles that one may accept that A and B are true, but not yet that if A and B are true then Z true. Achilles concurs. Then Tortoise agrees to accept

**C:** If A and B are true then Z is true;

but points out that one can similarly accept A, B and C but not conclude Z. Why? Because she says this needs *yet another* premise "If A and B and C are true then Z is true", and so on.

The infinite regress comes from the fact that application of a principle, here modus ponens, is different from declaring it, and in effect one application compresses infinitely many declarations. As Wittgenstein put it, "*there has to be a way to grasp a rule which is not an interpretation*". The Tortoise attempts to replace such practical grasping with endless interpretations, and effectively ends up rejecting modus ponens as a result. She asks for modus ponens to be substantiated before it is applied, instead of taking it on faith, and it turns out that it can not be so substantiated. If the Tortoise fails to grasp the rule there is nothing that can make it do so. Achilles can not make the Tortoise apply modus ponens by simply getting her to accept declarations. Even logic requires something extra-logical.

Comment: I disagree that logic requires "extra-logical". Logic is a different kind of truth to the truth that "Earth exists". Logical truths are defined to be true. I define a set of logical truths to be valid if and only if it does not lead to inconsistencies. And a valid set of logical truths has value if only if it has useful mappings onto the real world: I.e. you can take a set of known real-world truths and apply your logic to reach known or even previously unknown real-world truths. I think we're getting off-topic though: I just wanted to know if there was a name for the fallacy.

Comment: @bEPIK Yes, but that is not the point. Definitions only become effective in the real world, or even just in reasoning, if they are put into action. By refusing to put them into action Tortoise demonstrates that they are impotent even if the "logic" is declaratively accepted. The "extra-logical" is the actional part. As I said, there is no name.

Comment: You can certainly have a valid logic that doesn't contain modus ponens. Take the null set or the set that contains the definitional truth that every X is an X. These are valid logics. Of course, you would be utterly crippled in using existing real-world truths to reach new real-world truths within these logics. Logics are like a more formal kind of language. You can define "pen" however you like. And for some non-English ,language perhaps "pen" means something different. But just because someone is using a different language, doesn't mean I can disregard what they are saying as untrue.

Comment: I need to accept their definitions in order to understand the person, unless I can find a logical inconsistency in their definitions.

Comment: @bEPIK Wittgenstein's favorite response was "*and what if I don't?*" We are under no obligation to accept other person's conceptual system whether it is consistent or not (and by the way there are logics that allow inconsistencies). Mutual understanding may be better achieved by convincing them to switch to another. But what Tortoise illustrates goes further, people may be *incapable* of understanding us if they lack some practical ability to apply rules (like modus ponens). Wittgenstein reflected quite a bit on these issues, but this is way off-topic.

Comment: If you don't accept another person's valid definitions, then you are simply arguing semantics and there may be no actual disagreement.

Answer (score 1):

> What fallacy accepts P and P → Q but rejects Q (denies modus ponens)?

It turns out such reasoning is not necessarily fallacious, but rather reflects a philosophical viewpoint. Wikipedia, "Epistemic closure". The issue is not logical sufficiency, but what the observer can know.

> Epistemic closure is a property of some belief systems. It is the
>   principle that if a subject S knows p, and S knows that p entails q,
>   then S can thereby come to know q.
>
> ....
>
> While the principle of epistemic closure is generally regarded as
>   intuitive, philosophers such as Robert Nozick and Fred Dretske have
>   argued against it.

I would have thought this question was settled in favor of closure. That's what I like about this forum. You learn something new every day.

Comment: Wikipedia is not a good source, here is [SEP's Epistemic Closure](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/closure-epistemic). This is a different issue, in epistemic logic K(P) and P → Q does not entail K(Q). One can not settle for it because it is obviously false, take as P the axioms of arithmetic, and as Q any unproved theorem. But people do not "reject" Q when presented with a valid argument, as in OP, because of epistemic non-closure.

Comment: @Conifold. SEP is indeed the better source.  I am still surprised that closure exists as a philosophical issue.

Answer (score 1):

Look up "Counterfactual_thinking" on the Wikipedia:

> Counterfactual thinking is a concept in psychology that involves the
>   human tendency to create possible alternatives to life events that
>   have already occurred [...] These thoughts consist of the "What if?" and the "If I had
>   only..." that occur when thinking of how things could have turned out
>   differently.

Moreover, according the "Epistemology" section of the Wiki article on Robert Nozick, his:

> four conditions for S's knowing that P were:
>
> ```
> P is true
> S believes that P
> If it were the case that (not-P), S would not believe that P
> If it were the case that P, S would believe that P
> ```
>
> Nozick's third and fourth conditions are counterfactuals. He called
>   this the "tracking theory" of knowledge. Nozick believed the
>   counterfactual conditionals bring out an important aspect of our
>   intuitive grasp of knowledge: For any given fact, the believer's
>   method must reliably track the truth despite varying relevant
>   conditions. [...] Nozick believes that the truth tracking conditions
>   are more fundamental to human intuition than the principle of
>   deductive closure.